# How to fill a listBox with the all running applications

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder

Im trying to fill A listBox with A list of All running Applications (Im using C++ Builder) And by searching i found this code that don't Give me A list of the running applications only, it prints some unwanted text and the running applications

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <psapi.h>

void PrintProcessNameAndID( DWORD processID )
{
TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>");



HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                               PROCESS_VM_READ,
                               FALSE, processID );



if (NULL != hProcess )
{
    HMODULE hMod;
    DWORD cbNeeded;

    if ( EnumProcessModules( hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod), 
         &cbNeeded) )
    {
        GetModuleBaseName( hProcess, hMod, szProcessName, 
                           sizeof(szProcessName)/sizeof(TCHAR) );
    }
}



_tprintf( TEXT("%s  (PID: %u)\n"), szProcessName, processID );



CloseHandle( hProcess );
}

int main( void )
{


DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
unsigned int i;

if ( !EnumProcesses( aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded ) )
{
    return 1;
}



cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

for ( i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++ )
{
    if( aProcesses[i] != 0 )
    {
        PrintProcessNameAndID( aProcesses[i] );
    }
}

    return 0;
}
```

i know that this code is for console applications but if it worked i would edit it to run on c++ builder but its just dont.
So what is the right code ?

Comment: Your `for ( i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++ )` loop is based on the number of processes needed, not the actual number of processes in your array. If the number needed is larger than the array, then you are overrunning your array and operating on garbage process IDs.

Comment: @RaymondChen Actually, This is not my code, i found it on MSDN

Comment: @Kordy It is folly to paste code from the internet without checking it and understanding it.

Comment: Okay, now I see from the documentation that `cbNeeded` is incorrectly named. It should be `cbReturned`. That part of the code is correct, but misleading.

Answer (score 0):

That code should work for all processes, not just console ones. There might be more than one module, so technically it should be (old ANSI code from my website):

```
HANDLE hProc;
char szProcessName [80];
HMODULE ahMod [10];
DWORD dwNeeded;

hProc = OpenProcess (PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_READ,
                     FALSE,
                     dwPid);
if (hProc)
{
   if (EnumProcessModules (hProc, 
                           ahMod,
                           sizeof(ahMod),
                           &dwNeeded))
   {
      if (GetModuleBaseName (hProc, 
                             ahMod[0],
                             szProcessName,
                             sizeof(szProcessName)))
      {
         <success>
      }
      else
      {
         <failure>
      } 
   }
   CloseHandle (hProc);
}
```

Also as raymond points out, your loop is based on the size of your array (which would account for the garbage). This may be due to the MS help for EnumProcesses, which talks about dividing the array size by the size of a DWORD, but that's just to detect if the function has filled your array and you need to resubmit with more space. I guess you should zero out your process array before calling EnumProcesses i.e. use memset (or ZeroMemory, if C++ builder supports that macro).

Comment: i compiled your code and got [this error](http://www14.0zz0.com/2015/07/13/11/902220747.jpg) even after including `psapi.h` whats wrong ?